# Executing a jar file using a .bat file

Tags: java, batch-file, jar

I need to execute a jar file using a .bat file. The problem occurs here:

```
"java -Djava.library.path=timer -classpath .;timer\timer.jar"
```

There is a folder called "*timer*" within the folder in which I execute the .bat file and which contains the timer.jar. The jar is executed but it isn't using the timer I wanted it to use, instead I get a debug message that it wasn't possible to load the library and the program used the standard timer. I tried to add the library to the classpath manually, but that didn't work either. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So what is this external DLL/library you are using? Does it match your Java version? Does it match your Java "bits", i.e.: if Java is 64bit this library needs to be 64bit as well.

Comment: isn't java supposed to be machine-independent?

Comment: When you load *native* DLL how can it be machine independent?

Comment: sorry, I have no clue on this topic and no clue on how the dll was created

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way is to use a manifest file within the main jar to load all libraries.
using ide like netbeans or eclips will help.

Comment: sorry, I have no clue how to do that, I only have the .class files and the jar, no source